# contenteditable cancel push elements

Tags: javascript

**Hey friend, I need help...**
I made page with div "contentEditAble" and I want to cancel push divs / br / p
and stay it empty from elements after it's do function because it's do function that create massage like in "What'sApp Web" ...

The first lines (1-6) doesnt work to click enter but if clicking "send" button its work...

But please first you open the link in the div with contenteditable click at least twice times***enter*** and you  will Understand the problem...

You can see the link: jsfiddle.net/sarelyuval/nL1rbeL9

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 0):

```
var t = document.createTextNode(input.textContent); // line no 56
```

instead of input.innerHTML you need content input.textContent

Comment: and if i will join to it img, it will send also image?

Comment: try this div.innerHTML=input.innerHTML;  // line 57

Comment: sry i didn't get it can you please made changes on JSFiddle

Comment: double the text means? you are asking about spacing(<br>)?

Answer (score 0):

**I forgot to say, I want to add for it also Images (icons...)**

so I need only cancel push the divs and br in chrome